# More elegant/pythonic way of unpacking a list?

Tags: python, list

Is there a more elegant/pythonic way of unpacking this list?

```
feature_set = [['flew'], ['homes'], ['fly home']]
```

Into this:

```
flew|homes|fly home
```

without this ugly code:

```
output = ''
for feature in feature_set:
    if len(feature) < 2: output += ''.join(feature) + '|'
    if len(feature) > 1: output += ' '.join(feature) + '|'
print(output[:-1])
```

Comment: `'|'.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(feature_set))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first `join` each element of each inner list by `map`, and then `join` again for the `map` result

```
"|".join(map(lambda x: " ".join(x), feature_set))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `chain.from_iterable` to flatten list and then use `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain
feature_set = [['flew'], ['homes'], ['fly home']]

print("|".join(chain.from_iterable(feature_set)))
```

**Output:**

```
flew|homes|fly home
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want something like this.

```
'|'.join([inList[0] for inList in feature_set])
```